# CDI order of injecting and constructor

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi

Simple question, but I can't solve it. As I know fields are initialized first and after that constructor is called.

The following code

```
public class Controller {

        @Inject
        private ReadCommand readCommand;

        public Controller() {
            if (readCommand==null){
                System.out.println("NO");
            }else{
                System.out.println("YES");
            }        
        }
}
```

prints NO. But when I inject in constructor

```
@Inject
public Controller(ReadCommand readCommand)
```

It prints YES. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're doing nothing wrong.  The constructor is called many times during the injection process.  The fields are injected into the managed bean only once it's been constructed.  When you do constructor level injection, your constructor needs to read:

```
private ReadCommand readCommand;

@Inject
public Controller(ReadCommand readCommand) {
    this.readCommand = readCommand;
    if(this.readCommand == null) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. Can I inject in myField and to get myField in constructor in such way that the myField has already bean initialized via CDI container?

Comment: And could you explain: "The constructor is called many times during the injection process." ?

Comment: You can't get it in the constructor.  You can use a `@PostConstruct` call back from the container to do initialization work after the injection is done.  The constructor may be called multiple times, since the object you deal with is a proxy.  This is typically a non-issue for people.